# why when I want to disable scroll in textview the text view will going down under the keyboard in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3, scroll, uitextview

I have a text view in my project that I want to expand when user input more that 20 characters so I used this method

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {

   if chatTexts.text.characters.count > 20 {

        print("up to 20")
        chatTexts.isScrollEnabled = false

     }
```

and when keyboard is going up i used this to move text view to the top of keyboard

```
func keyboardShown(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let infoKey  = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey],
        let rawFrame = (infoKey as AnyObject).cgRectValue {
        let keyboardFrame = view.convert(rawFrame, from: nil)
        self.heightKeyboard = keyboardFrame.size.height

        levelChatViewController.sizeForOffsetKeyboard = heightKeyboard!

            if levelChatViewController.sizeForOffsetKeyboard == 253.0 {

                print("the size is 253.0")

                animateViewMoving(up: true, moveValue: 207)

            } else {

                print("the size is 216.0")

                animateViewMoving(up: true, moveValue: 167)


            }
            }
```

But when the user start to write some texts in textview the textview will going down under the keyboard

**remember that before adding textViewDidChange every thing was ok and the textview was going to the top of the keyboard and the only problem was that doesn't scroll so I used textViewDidChange method to do that but this problem happend**

Comment: when you change the size of the uitextview, you have to push it up more by the size you added

Comment: you mean I have to add to the value of the up ?

Comment: yes!, can you please try it and get back to me?

Comment: ok please wait I will check

Comment: No it doesn't worked even when I used 400 value when user is editing textview the textview will going to the bottom behind keyboard

Comment: are you using constraints?

Comment: I use them because in story board they have to be fixed and this was ok before using textview scroll method